# Не получается удалить элемент json JS

Tags: javascript, json

Есть строка, которая хранится в localstorage в формате json.

Получаю данные из localstorage:

```
 var cart = localStorage['cart'];
```

Пытаюсь удалить :

```
cart.splice(itemId,itemId);
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
   cart.splice is not a function
```

Консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD 2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage['cart']);
cart.splice(itemId, 1);
```

*Update*

Ага! Я не знаю, что Вы сохраняете в `localStorage`, но с тем, что Вы получаете обратно, надо делать так:

```
var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage['cart']);
cart["1"].splice(itemId, 1);
```

*Update 2*

"А можно удалить массив целиком?"

```
delete cart["1"];
```

Comment: Ошибка та же самая, console.log(cart) делаю - выводит объект корректно. Делаю splice, выдает ошибку в консоли Uncaught TypeError: cart.splice is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.addToCart

Comment: @КириллЖелнов выводит не объект, а строку. Добавьте в вопрос, что Вы видите в консоли. А также `console.log(typeof cart);`

Comment: попробовал, сделал еще console.log(typeof cart);

Comment: @КириллЖелнов см. *Update* в ответе. Чему равен Ваш `itemId`?

Comment: Да, теперь работает, но не совсем так, как я хотел. Удаляет первый элемент из 1 массива. А можно удалить массив целиком?